# How do I get the raw (RAW!) URL in an Azure Web Site?

Tags: azure, url-rewriting, proxy, azure-web-app-service, server-variables

I'm deploying an Azure Web Site and I want to get at the raw url, before anything messes with it. I'm finding, though, that by the time my site gets involved, the URL has already been cleaned up a bit. For instance:

> http://url-tests.azurewebsites.net/////
>   (I made that for this question, you can try it)

From the app, I have checked all sorts of things but they don't show what I expect **in Azure** (where are all those other slashes?):

```
UNENCODED_URL: /
HTTP_URL: /
REQUEST_URI: /
X-FORWARDED-FOR: 
X-FOO: 
HTTP_X_REWRITE_URL: 
HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_URL: /
Request.RawUrl: /
Request.Url.ToString(): http://url-tests.azurewebsites.net/
```

For reference, when I run the app **locally** with IIS Express, or IIS 7, **I see what I expect** (at least in some of the variables):

```
UNENCODED_URL: /////
HTTP_URL: /////
```

What gives? Is Azure stripping things out? If so, how can I get back to what the browser actually requested? (I *did* verify with Fiddler that the browser is requesting the URL with all those extra slashes.)

(Also, the slashes are just an example. I'm not really building an app that expects to see 5 slashes in a row.)

**Update:** checked `HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_URL`, too (added to list above). No dice

Comment: There's an ARR layer that sits in front of Windows Azure Web Sites to perform actions like sticky sessions. Perhaps this is doing some scrubbing of the URI before it gets routed to your individual web site.

Comment: @BrentDaCodeMonkey sure, but I would have expected to still have access to the original request via a header, variable, etc. Surely there must be _some way_ to get to it?

Comment: what is this written in: pure HTML? MVC?

Comment: @viperguynaz MVC, though I doubt that matters...? (It *does* work locally, but not from Azure, which is likely behind some load balancer/proxy)

Comment: This url muck business means I can do things like http://url-tests.azurewebsites.net/////home////index////, which clearly shouldn't work, but does in Azure.

Comment: Azure Cloud services definitely run behind a load balancer.  This allows you to smoothly transition from Staging slot to Production slot with a VIP swap.  The user session is sticky after a VIP swap. But, I just did a quick VS2012 MVC 4 app with a breakpoint in Application_BeginRequest() and http://localhost:6015///// returns "/" in all the request object URLs.

Comment: @Michael, have you tried your scenario locally in `IIS8`. Azure WebSites run on `IIS8`, and as I see the comment from viperguynaz it seems that the stripping comes more from the `IIS8` instead of anything else.

Comment: @viperguynaz interesting! did you check the server variables, too (i.e. not just `Request.RawUrl`)?

Comment: @astaykov I'll spin up a Server 2012 box and check, good idea.